# Is it normal to have a MBP's temp at ~50?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

My MBP runs very hot and I thought the fans were broken because there's no air blowing out the back and no fan noise as I used to hear in my older MBP so I installed [macs fan control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control/download)

Apparently, the fans are running mostly at around ~1200rpm and the temps are 50-55c, is this normal? should I modify the settings?

I can even feel the heat just from using the keyboard.

Comment: What is the temperature in the room where you have the MBP?

Comment: Not really sure, but I'd say easily 30-35c since it's a second-floor gym room with just a small fan and feels pretty hot, it's also 42c outside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have indicated that your ambient room temperature is easily 35 degrees C, possibly up to 42 degrees C - then I do not find it abnormal that the temperature of your MacBook Pro is 50 degrees C.

The CPU in your MacBook Pro is not hurt by the fact that the temperature is 50 degrees C.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I'll remove mac fan control then.

Comment: While the  50ºC temperature of the Mac itself may not be worrying, 35ºC is at the extreme end of the 'ambient temperature' at which Apple advises that you can use the laptop. If the room were any hotter, I wouldn't use the Mac. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201640